# Python:Understaning operation on list

Tags: python, list

I have seen this code

```
l = [2,3,4,4,5,6,3]
c = (10001)*[0]
for i in l:
    c[i] = c[i]+1
m = max(c)
print m,c.index(m)
```

it prints 3 2
it looks like it store two things
Here what does (10001)*[0] and what does it do?

Comment: What did you see when you tried typing `c = (10001)*0` into your Python interpreter?

Comment: If you ran it, you would see that it assigns `0` to `c`. Which means you'd get an exception when running `c[i] = c[i]+1`.

Comment: when i try it out in the python terminal, it just makes c `0`. Is that exactly as the code was where you saw it? It will raise an exception in it's current form.

Comment: It's like writing `c = 0`, weird thing to do. Keep doing this and everyone will hate you :(

Comment: Do you even try to run this?
http://codepad.org/HJ2mhx4L

Comment: sorry for typing error please see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this code looked like:

```
l = [2,3,4,4,5,6,3]
c = [0]*10001
for i in l:
    c[i] = c[i]+1
m = max(c)
print m
```

where `c = [0]*10001` creates list of 10001 zeros inside. `c = (10001)*0` is nothing else than `0`

Answer (score 0):

Here (10001) * [0] can be re-written as 10001 * [0], the parentheses are redundant.
This just creates a list with 10001 0's